# XR2206 Function Generator Kit on LM2917N-14

Tags: circuit-analysis

Please forgive my bad language.

I am making a vehicle speed indicator with an LM2917N-14 frequency-to-voltage convertor ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2917-n.pdf?ts=1597402039722)). I tried it with a cheap XR2206 function generator and an NE555 variable square wave.

With the NE555, the LM2917 is working properly, the output voltage follows the input frequency (even though 5 V supply NE555).
However, with XR2206 in both sine and square wave there is no DC output on LM2917 even using a 12 V supply for the XR2206.

At first I thought the XR2206 output had to be buffered/amplified before it was fed to the LM2917, but it still didn't work. (I use simple TLC2272 op-amp as a buffer/amplifier.)

The XR2206 itself is normal, has a frequency and DC out of sine and square wave (I measured it with DMM because I don't have an oscilloscope).

My question is why can't the XR2206 drive the LM2917? What should be added so that the XR2206 can drive the LM2917?

I really hope the answers, Thank you .....

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 555-based signal generator very probably has an output which goes down to almost 0 V.

With a 12 V supply, the output of the XR2206 function generator will be centred around 6 V.

Here is an oscilloscope display showing what you are working with:

[image: Output signal of an XR2206 at 440 Hz showing numerical statistics]

The yellow "1" marker on the left is at 0 V. The vertical scale is 2 V/div. I set it to show all the measurements.

Looking at the datasheet for the LM2917N-14, it seems to me that you need a 10 kΩ, or maybe 15 kΩ, resistor instead of the 1N4148 diode, so that it makes a voltage divider to raise the switching threshold for the LM2917 to a sufficently high voltage.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it according to the attached image and it works perfectly both sine and square wave.
Thank you very much for your advice and lessons .....
God bless you.......

[image]